# Is there a way to make messages appear when you hover over a variable or object in eclipse/java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Inside coding, rather than in the final result, is there a way to set a message to appear the same way descriptions of classes and methods appear in eclipse? It would make it much easier to describe my objects in a way I can see anywhere on the page.

Comment: What are you asking? Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided you use [javadoc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) for your classes and variables.